# СИ, как в многофайловом проекте объявит структуру

Tags: c, структуры

Где и как мне объявить структуру в многофайловом проекте, в main.c или в funcs.h(если я использую структуру и main.c и в func.c)

Comment: очевидно, что это должно быть в том файле, который используется всеми, кому нужна эта структура. В Вашем случае  funcs.h хорош кандидат, если включить его в main.c и в func.c

Comment: Объявить *тип* структуры - в заголовочном файле, объявлять переменные - в зависимости от использования. Если локальные - в файлах исходников, если глобальные - как `extern` в заголовочном...